# Android dialog in another application

Tags: java, android, dialog

My use case is very specific so I will explain it as detailed as I can.

I am developing an android application. I call this application A. Then there is an pre-existing application B. B is a navigation app that I cannot alter.

I want to show a dialog or pop-up whenever something special occurs in application B. for example app A receives a message through a broadcast that a dialog should be shown. then code in App A should be able to show a dialog in app B.

Is this possible to do in android? can I show a dialog outside of an application? if it is not then is it possible to show a dialog on the OS itself perhaps? I would like to ask if you can answer in a simple manner as I am not that experienced with android to begin with.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Short answer: no it is not possible in your case. 
"then code in App A should be able to show a dialog in app B." - this requires work on the side of B application. If B application was developed by you then you could add a service or a broadcast listener that would react to actions from the application A.

Comment: Okay. but what about the the android OS. can I create a dialog in the OS while App A is still in the background? Because that would work as well.

Comment: Assuming you have a way to detect the something special, you could probably do it, but you'd need to be wary of background activity launch restrictions.